# PHP parse error for opening curly bracket

Tags: php, debugging

I am getting this unfamiliar error when running the code bellow. I can't see what's wrong.

Error:
**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/crawler/sources.php on line 2**

```
<?php
sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){

if (is_readable($filename)){
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);

return(json_decode($contents));

} else {
return NULL;
}

}



print_r(sourcesList());
?>
```

This is the exact code snippet I run. What's wrong?

Comment: sourcelist() looks like a function with one optional parameter, if this is the case you need to prefix it with `function sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){'. You might want to check the file exists before checking it's readable.

Comment: @GregK `is_readable` "Tells whether a file exists and is readable" ([manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-readable.php))

Comment: @lonesomeday I didn't know it checked for existence, I've learned something new :) Thanks! I'll use that in future when reading files.

Comment: @GregK The things you learn when you read the documentation... ;-)

Comment: @lonesomeday Just seen you live in St. Albans too, what are the chances!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to define a function, but you've missed out the `function` keyword:

```
sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){
```

should be

```
function sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){
```

[See the documentation on PHP functions.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the function keyword:

```
function sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){
```

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect

```
sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){

}
```

to do?
Never heard of that construct

Comment: duh, now that I see the answers, it's obvious

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are trying to **define** a `sourcelist` function here (with one argument that has a default value). You forgot to start the function declaration with the `function` keyword. So your code starts with a **call** to the `sourcelist` function followed by the start of a block (which isn't allowed there).

The second line should read:

```
function sourcelist($filename = '/var/resources/sources.list'){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this

```
<?php
$filename = "/var/resources/sources.list"

function sourcelist($filename){

     if (is_readable($filename)){
     $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
     $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
     fclose($handle);
     return(json_decode($contents));
     } else {
     return NULL;
     }

}

print_r(sourcesList($filename));
?>
```